# Issue Calling html With AngularJS ng-Include or Directive

Tags: html, angularjs

I want to implement AngularJS's ng-include statement into my website to reduce code redundancy, but having trouble getting it to fully work. Currently, my `index.html` page is calling `pageLayout.html` My `index.html` is calling `pageLayout.html` successfully, but when adding a `<h1>` tag in `index.html` I cant put it on top of the `pageLayout.html` content that I call. Does anyone have any ideas?

Here is the link: http://plnkr.co/edit/uarelZgzmITJXg2pYXfg?p=preview

I have also tried using a directive like the following: http://plnkr.co/edit/VmAO47l7RMXTGYYFFgLB?p=preview but still having issues.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you move the h1 out of the div that has the ng-include on it and put it above that as a sibling node?

Comment: your code worked for me. Add a p tag with some text to payLagout.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The transclusion strategy is set to `element` not to `true` so you can not insert extra content.

Moreover the content is wiped [everytime the template value changes](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngInclude.js#L201)

And using transclusion with ngInclude [does not make sense](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngInclude.js#L234-L239)

I would rather use a directive with transclusion (or bind the title) if you want to avoid code duplication, something like

```
directive('pageContainer',function(){
  return {
      template:'<div class="divSize" ><h1>{{title}}</h1><div ng-transclude></div></div>',
      scope:{
        title:"@"
      }
  }
})
```

Comment: +1 BUT: using transclusion with ngInclude does not make sense? really? https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6580 I can think of many other examples where it makes a lot of sense, that's why they are actually working into allow transclusion within the ng-include directive.

Comment: You are right, I was quoting the source code. Although, I think you can "still" use a simple directive with a template allowing transclusion, especially if you use ngInclude with static template. And the issue with css selector mentioned in the github issue is for me bad css class design rather than issue with angular. But of course if you rely on third party library it is more complicated :)

Comment: More verbose but you could use [ngSwitch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch) or use different routing. But anyway you are right I understand people may want this feature. My point is that I think (as a personal thought) we could do without

Comment: @laurent thanks for the reply... I am really new to AngularJS, so am a little unsure of how to implement this into my example. Could you be a little more specific? Thanks.

Comment: [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/1nx4vwXgJnJUn5CHinQX?p=preview) shows you how to have a variable title always within h1 element, and a variable body content

Comment: @laurent thanks for the feedback... However, it still doesn't work. I wrote this in plunker, any suggestions? http://plnkr.co/edit/VmAO47l7RMXTGYYFFgLB?p=preview

Comment: Currently, it displays the text like it should in `index.html` but the background color isn't there.

Comment: There are few mistakes:

1. you need to normalize your directive <pageContent> -> <page-content>

2. `templateUrl` and not `templateURL`

3. you need to tell where in the template you want to insert the transcluded content

[corrected](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZzyxKpwq0juHBFAlNJ4t?p=preview)